# The solution of differential equation $2xy+6x+(x^2-4)y'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When I solved the above DE, I reached to the step and confused how to continue

$2x(y+3)+(x^2-4)dy/dx$

$(x^2-4)  dy/dx=-2x(y+3)$

$dy/(y+3)=-2x/(x^2-4) dx$

$∫dy/(y+3)=∫-2x/(x^2-4) dx$

$\ln⁡|y+3|=-ln⁡|x^2-4|+C$

$\ln⁡|y+3|+ln⁡|x^2-4|=C$

$\ln⁡|(y+3)(x^2-4)|=C$

$|(y+3)(x^2-4)|=e^C$

then how can  I get the function $y$ for the last equation and when I checked the solution by W.F, I found it  as
$y=c/(x^2-4)-3x^2/(x^2-4)$

plz can anyone help me to show how  happed that
thanks

Comment: The difference is just in the integration constant. You know that you can replace $\pm e^c$ with a general constant $C$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I know that but can you explain how to get the same solution of W.F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note from
$$ \ln⁡|(y+3)(x^2-4)|=C$$
you have
$$ y=-3+\frac{C}{x^2-4}=\frac{-3x^2+12+C}{x^2-4}=\frac{-3x^2}{x^2-4}+\frac{12+C}{x^2-4} $$
Now define $C_1=12+C$ and you have
$$ y=\frac{-3x^2}{x^2-4}+\frac{C_1}{x^2-4} $$
which is the same as the answer.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Hum, @Samir I'd like to precise something that is actually hidden. From $|(y+3)(x^2-4)|=e^C>0$ you get rid of the absolute value $(y+3)(x^2-4)=C'$ with $C'=\pm e^C\neq 0$ to which you add $0$ because $y=-3$ is solution of initial ODE. So in the end $C$ being arbitrary you get an arbitrary $C''\in\mathbb R$ and $(y+3)(x^2-4)=C''$, but the same letter was actually used...

Answer (score 1):

From this step you use exponential
$$\ln\vert y+3\vert=-\ln\vert x^2-4\vert +C$$
$$\Rightarrow e^{\ln\vert y+3\vert}=e^{-\ln\vert x^2-4\vert +C}$$
$$\Rightarrow \vert y+3\vert=\frac{e^C}{e^{\ln\vert x^2-4\vert}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \vert y+3\vert=\frac{K}{\vert x^2-4\vert}$$
For some positive number $K$
$$\Rightarrow y+3=\frac{K}{x^2-4}\text{ or }y+3=-\frac{K}{x^2-4}$$
Which by allowing $K$ to be positive or negative can be consolidated to become
$$\Rightarrow y+3=\frac{K}{x^2-4}$$
$$\Rightarrow y=\frac{K}{x^2-4}-3; K\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Now the solution that you saw is equivalent to this one since when you take a common denominator you get
$$\Rightarrow y=\frac{-3x^2+12+K}{x^2-4}$$
And taking $12+K$ to be a constant
$C’$ you get
$$\Rightarrow y=\frac{-3x^2+C’}{x^2-4}$$
Which is the solution you saw in the answer sheet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but the solution of W.F is not same your solution

Comment: Yes it is, I added the explanation

Comment: thank you sir .........

Comment: It is my pleasure 

Answer (score 1):

$$2xy+6x+(x^2-4)y'=0$$
It's easier to rewrite the DE as:
$$((x^2-4)y)'=-6x$$
Integrate:
$$(x^2-4)y=-3x^2+C$$